# jq: reshaping with additional statistics on the sub-arrays of an array of objects - cmake compile_commands.json

Tags: cmake, jq

I'm working with jq to process cmake generated compile_commands.json files, which are very simplistic and don't contain direct information about the targets or an easy way to see what files are getting compiled multiple times, and whether there are duplicates for different targets, etc.  Sohrt version, is that there can be a lot of tooling problems when duplication happens and when there are not easy ways to select subsets of the compile commands database (ccdb).

Maybe there are better ways to do this than jq, but I'm getting frustrated with jq working at a second level of depth... and I'd like to learn what I'm missing here.

Here is an example compile_commands.json:

```
[
  {
     "directory": "/repository/build/build",
     "command": "/usr/bin/gcc -Wall -DMACRO_FOR_X1 -o src/lib/X_core1/CMakeFiles/X_core.dir/src/A.c.o -c src/lib/A.c",
     "file": "src/lib/A.c"
  },

  {
     "directory": "/repository/build/build",
     "command": "/usr/bin/gcc -Wall -DMACRO_FOR_Y1 -o src/lib/X_core2/CMakeFiles/Y_core.dir/src/A.c.o -c src/lib/A.c",
     "file": "src/lib/A.c"
  },

  {
     "directory": "/repository/build/build",
     "command": "/usr/bin/gcc -Wall -DMACRO_FOR_Z1 -DBOBS_SPECIAL_MACRO -o src/lib/Z_core/CMakeFiles/Z_core.dir/src/A.c.o -c src/lib/A.c",
     "file": "src/lib/A.c"
  },

  {
     "directory": "/repository/build/build",
     "command": "/usr/bin/gcc -Wall -DMACRO_FOR_Z1 -DBOBS_SPECIAL_MACRO -o src/lib/Z_core/CMakeFiles/Z_core.dir/src/B.c.o -c src/lib/B.c",
     "file": "src/lib/B.c"

  },

  {
     "directory": "/repository/build/build",
     "command": "/usr/bin/gcc -Wall -DMACRO_FOR_X1 -o src/lib/X_core/CMakeFiles/X_core.dir/src/B.c.o -c src/lib/B.c",
     "file": "src/lib/B.c"
  },

  {
     "directory": "/repository/build/build",
     "command": "/usr/bin/gcc -Wall -DMACRO_FOR_Z1 -DBOBS_SPECIAL_MACRO -o src/lib/Z_core/CMakeFiles/Z_core.dir/src/C.c.o -c src/lib/C.c",
     "file": "src/lib/C.c"
  }
]
```

I've already got a jq script that allows me to select a subset of the ccdb based upon 1+ targets - that was easy enough.

What I'd like to be able to generate for analysis to understand if we need to look at refactoring builds, looking at dependencies for different translation units for the same .c files, etc.

Right now, I have target extraction with the following jq function in a `ccdb.jq` file that I'm including.  I also have a function at the end of it that gets me a partial solution - the array from the top layer (:

```
def cmake_command_parts(command): # Split the command into its parts
                                 # Compiler, flags, output, file
    command |
    capture(
        "(?<compiler>[\\/a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\-_\\+]*)\\s*(?<flags>[\\/a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\-_\\+=\\s\\\\\"]*?)-o\\s*(?<output>[a-zA-z0-9_\\-\\/]*CMakeFiles\\/(?<target>[a-zA-z0-9_\\- \\/]*).dir[\\/a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\-_\\+]*.o)\\s*-c\\s*(?<filename>[\\/a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\-_\\+]*)"
        )
;

def cmake_target_from_command(command): # Define a function to capture a target per cmake ccdb behavior
                    # Mostly a simple wrapper around the pattern - just pulls out the target
    command | cmake_command_parts(.).target
    
; # end of capture_cmake_target

def cmake_unique_targets(ccdb): # Get the list of unique targets from the cmake ccdb
    ccdb |
    [cmake_target_from_command(.[].command)] | unique | .[]
; # end of cmake_unique_targets


def duped_file_info(ccdb): # Collect dupe info and related commands
    ccdb |
    group_by(.file) | .[] |= {
        file: .[].file,
        dupes: length,
        commands: [ cmake_command_parts(.[].command) as $cmdParts | {
            target: $cmdParts.target,
            compiler: $cmdParts.compiler,
            flags: $cmdParts.flags,
            output: $cmdParts.output,
            file: $cmdParts.filename
        }] 
    } 

; # end of duped_file_info
```

duped_file_info gets me the following when I pass it the ccdb:

```
[
  {
    "file": "src/lib/A.c",
    "dupes": 3,
    "commands": [
      {
        "target": "X_core",
        "compiler": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "flags": "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_X1 ",
        "output": "src/lib/X_core1/CMakeFiles/X_core.dir/src/A.c.o",
        "file": "src/lib/A.c"
      },
      {
        "target": "Y_core",
        "compiler": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "flags": "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_Y1 ",
        "output": "src/lib/X_core2/CMakeFiles/Y_core.dir/src/A.c.o",
        "file": "src/lib/A.c"
      },
      {
        "target": "Z_core",
        "compiler": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "flags": "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_Z1 -DBOBS_SPECIAL_MACRO ",
        "output": "src/lib/Z_core/CMakeFiles/Z_core.dir/src/A.c.o",
        "file": "src/lib/A.c"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "file": "src/lib/B.c",
    "dupes": 2,
    "commands": [
      {
        "target": "Z_core",
        "compiler": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "flags": "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_Z1 -DBOBS_SPECIAL_MACRO ",
        "output": "src/lib/Z_core/CMakeFiles/Z_core.dir/src/B.c.o",
        "file": "src/lib/B.c"
      },
      {
        "target": "X_core",
        "compiler": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "flags": "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_X1 ",
        "output": "src/lib/X_core/CMakeFiles/X_core.dir/src/B.c.o",
        "file": "src/lib/B.c"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "file": "src/lib/C.c",
    "dupes": 1,
    "commands": [
      {
        "target": "Z_core",
        "compiler": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "flags": "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_Z1 -DBOBS_SPECIAL_MACRO ",
        "output": "src/lib/Z_core/CMakeFiles/Z_core.dir/src/C.c.o",
        "file": "src/lib/C.c"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What I want to be able to produce would look like the following:

```
[
  {
    "file": "src/lib/A.c",
    "dupes": 3,
    "uniqueFlagCnt": 3,
    "uniqueFlags": [
      "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_X1 ",
      "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_Y1 ",
      "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_Z1 -DBOBS_SPECIAL_MACRO "
    ],
    "commands": [
      {
        "target": "X_core",
        "compiler": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "flags": "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_X1 ",
        "output": "src/lib/X_core1/CMakeFiles/X_core.dir/src/A.c.o",
        "file": "src/lib/A.c"
      },
      {
        "target": "Y_core",
        "compiler": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "flags": "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_Y1 ",
        "output": "src/lib/X_core2/CMakeFiles/Y_core.dir/src/A.c.o",
        "file": "src/lib/A.c"
      },
      {
        "target": "Z_core",
        "compiler": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "flags": "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_Z1 -DBOBS_SPECIAL_MACRO ",
        "output": "src/lib/Z_core/CMakeFiles/Z_core.dir/src/A.c.o",
        "file": "src/lib/A.c"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "file": "src/lib/B.c",
    "dupes": 2,
    "uniqueFlagCnt": 2,
    "uniqueFlags": [
      "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_Z1 -DBOBS_SPECIAL_MACRO ",
      "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_X1 ",
    ],
    "commands": [
      {
        "target": "Z_core",
        "compiler": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "flags": "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_Z1 -DBOBS_SPECIAL_MACRO ",
        "output": "src/lib/Z_core/CMakeFiles/Z_core.dir/src/B.c.o",
        "file": "src/lib/B.c"
      },
      {
        "target": "X_core",
        "compiler": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "flags": "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_X1 ",
        "output": "src/lib/X_core/CMakeFiles/X_core.dir/src/B.c.o",
        "file": "src/lib/B.c"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "file": "src/lib/C.c",
    "dupes": 1,
    "uniqueFlagCnt": 1,
    "uniqueFlags": [
      "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_Z1 -DBOBS_SPECIAL_MACRO "
    ],
    "commands": [
      {
        "target": "Z_core",
        "compiler": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "flags": "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_Z1 -DBOBS_SPECIAL_MACRO ",
        "output": "src/lib/Z_core/CMakeFiles/Z_core.dir/src/C.c.o",
        "file": "src/lib/C.c"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Where I'm having difficulty is on accessing the `.commands.[].command.flags` to get the unique list and count them to put in that part. I have been trying to do it in two function stages where I pass what I can get from `duped_file_info` to a second function to stuff in the details on unique flags.  But when I do that, I can't seem to get passed the syntax errors.

I've tried working with the foreach syntax as well, but I am clearly misunderstanding that as well.

Any hints, suggestions, or redirects would be greatly appreciated.  I am assuming that my issue lies in the nature of jq and being able to access and analyze the sub-arrays - because the approach for processing the top level array works no problem.

Comment: Should that be `"uniqueFlagCnt": 1` in the last one?

Comment: As a minor side note: `def f: g; a | f` would be more idiomatic to jq than `def f(x): x | g; f(a)`.

Comment: Fixed last `"uniqueFlagCnt": `, thank you for the catch

Comment: for the idiomatic comment, a follow-up question.  I actually have those definitions in a file called  `ccdb.jq` file I'm including locally with a  `jq 'include "ccdb"; duped_file_info(.)'` style call.  Should that syntax be the same when those definitions are in a separate file like that?

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying now...  parameters ok but less idiomatic....

Comment: @Matt There's nothing wrong with functions taking arguments. But if all they filter is the original context (the function body starts out with `arg | …`, and `arg` doesn't appear anywhere else), then providing to the function an already filtered context would render the implementation more [point-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming#jq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few details missing, but this should get you there:

```
def parse_command:
   capture( "(?<compiler>[\\/a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\-_\\+]*)\\s*(?<flags>[\\/a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\-_\\+=\\s\\\\\"]*?)-o\\s*(?<output>[a-zA-z0-9_\\-\\/]*CMakeFiles\\/(?<target>[a-zA-z0-9_\\- \\/]*).dir[\\/a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\-_\\+]*.o)\\s*-c\\s*(?<filename>[\\/a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\-_\\+]*)" )
;

group_by( .file ) |
map(
   {
      file: .[0].file,
      commands: map( .command | parse_command )
   } |
   .uniqueFlags = ( .commands | map( .flags ) | unique )
)
```

```json
[
  {
    "file": "src/lib/A.c",
    "commands": [
      {
        "compiler": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "flags": "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_X1 ",
        "output": "src/lib/X_core1/CMakeFiles/X_core.dir/src/A.c.o",
        "target": "X_core",
        "filename": "src/lib/A.c"
      },
      {
        "compiler": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "flags": "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_Y1 ",
        "output": "src/lib/X_core2/CMakeFiles/Y_core.dir/src/A.c.o",
        "target": "Y_core",
        "filename": "src/lib/A.c"
      },
      {
        "compiler": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "flags": "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_Z1 -DBOBS_SPECIAL_MACRO ",
        "output": "src/lib/Z_core/CMakeFiles/Z_core.dir/src/A.c.o",
        "target": "Z_core",
        "filename": "src/lib/A.c"
      }
    ],
    "uniqueFlags": [
      "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_X1 ",
      "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_Y1 ",
      "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_Z1 -DBOBS_SPECIAL_MACRO "
    ]
  },
  {
    "file": "src/lib/B.c",
    "commands": [
      {
        "compiler": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "flags": "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_Z1 -DBOBS_SPECIAL_MACRO ",
        "output": "src/lib/Z_core/CMakeFiles/Z_core.dir/src/B.c.o",
        "target": "Z_core",
        "filename": "src/lib/B.c"
      },
      {
        "compiler": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "flags": "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_X1 ",
        "output": "src/lib/X_core/CMakeFiles/X_core.dir/src/B.c.o",
        "target": "X_core",
        "filename": "src/lib/B.c"
      }
    ],
    "uniqueFlags": [
      "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_X1 ",
      "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_Z1 -DBOBS_SPECIAL_MACRO "
    ]
  },
  {
    "file": "src/lib/C.c",
    "commands": [
      {
        "compiler": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "flags": "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_Z1 -DBOBS_SPECIAL_MACRO ",
        "output": "src/lib/Z_core/CMakeFiles/Z_core.dir/src/C.c.o",
        "target": "Z_core",
        "filename": "src/lib/C.c"
      }
    ],
    "uniqueFlags": [
      "-Wall -DMACRO_FOR_Z1 -DBOBS_SPECIAL_MACRO "
    ]
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/XjKWRMXHWbF) on jqplay

Comment: Question:  What's the reason for using the zeroth index for the map?  I see its going through the whole array, but using the zeroth index specifically is not intuitive for me here...  perhaps that's part of why I'm not understanding the root of my problem.

Comment: FWIW, you got me there!  Thank you. [Updated JQ Play with the filter I'll factor into its own function](https://jqplay.org/s/iFgJYNJSYcn).  Minor update, given the cascading, is there an easy way to reorder to put the two unique fields ahead of the list of commands?

Comment: @Matt, Re "*What's the reason for using the zeroth index for the map?*",  Well, you don't need to take the file name from the first element since every element has the same file name, but what other element did you have in mind?

Comment: @Matt, Objects are *unordered* lists of key-value pairs. That's all I say on that subject.

Comment: Replaced a `group_by` with a simpler `unique`.